# Can not run the simple docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM armhfbuild/debian

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y transmission-daemon \
  && service transmission-daemon stop   

RUN mkdir /root/media \
  && chmod 777 /root/media/ 

RUN apt-get install -y curl 

EXPOSE 9091 51413/tcp 51413/udp

ADD settings.json /etc/transmission-daemon/

ADD init.sh /

CMD [ "/init.sh" ]
```

Build:

`docker build --tag=private/trans .`

I am trying to run:

```
docker run -p 9091:9091 -p 51413:51413 -p 51413:51413/udp -d private/trans
dbb1ba0e840acc575bcbe1c87a79e7760fef4c43c587875cea110b74b1bf67e5
```

But the container does not start and logs Nothing.

`docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

`docker logs dbb1ba0e840acc575bcbe1c87a79e7760fef4c43c587875cea110b74b1bf67e5`:

```
Starting bittorrent daemon: transmission-daemon.
```

`init.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

service transmission-daemon start
```

What can be related to the problem? 
Why docker container does not start?

Comment: It starts but also ends because init.sh terminates after the "start" command.

Comment: After the "service start" line you may add another command, namely `exec sh -i`, to run an interactive shell. You will of course not really use that interactive shell, but that shell also won't close automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said Paul Stelian, your command terminates.

Have a look, for example at

https://github.com/magna-z/docker-transmission/blob/master/Dockerfile

you see the last line is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["transmission-daemon", "--foreground"]
```

Another way would be to replace

```
service transmission-daemon start
```

by

```
service transmission-daemon start ; sleep infinity
```

or

```
service transmission-daemon start ; tail -f /dev/null
```